# boost.serialization and replace existing method of serializing std::wstring

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I need to serialize std::wstring by my own method.
How to force boost to use my methods of serialization instead of default methods?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but you'd want to specialize boost::serialization::archive for your data type:

```
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, std::wstring& s, const unsigned int version)
{
    for (std::wstring::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
        ar >> *it
}

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

This code should basically work as-is, you'd just want to change the contents of the serialize function (but not the signature.)

Why you'd want to serialize a wstring in any other way than just *printing* it (ie. just using normal iostreams), I have no idea.

Comment: any ideas?

test code here: http://liveworkspace.org/code/5f8a62c02c8cf96a909666ad8b40a6e5